# Legendre Transformations and a decrease in Helmholtz free energy

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose we have a system placed in a thermal reservoir, and the system is free to exchange energy but not volume or particles with the reservoir. Under these conditions, it can be shown that an increase in the total entropy of the reservoir + system is equivalent to a decrease in the Helmholtz free energy of the reservoir. In other words, the system will spontaneously tend toward the state of lowest Helmholtz free energy.

This statement, though, seems trivial.

Let
$$F(T,...)=-TS+U(S,...)$$ where $T=\partial U / \partial S$ and

To find the minimum value of $F$ differentiate with respect to $T:$

$$\partial F / \partial T = 0=S$$

So this would mean that the reservoir would tend toward the state of zero entropy.

So again, what is meant that a system will spontaneously tend toward the state of lowest Helmholtz free energy?

Comment: The quantity you are talking about is usually called the Helmholtz free energy. The Gibbs free energy also involves  a mechanical work reservoir along with the thermal reservoir. Regarding the Helmholtz free energy here is a recent question whose answer you may find useful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737346/thermodynamic-potential-minimization/737394?noredirect=1#comment1650528_737394

Comment: His $G$ ("$G=TS - U$") is the negative of the Helmholtz free energy.

Comment: @hyportnex I was using this link https://web.physics.wustl.edu/alford/physics/Legendre_introduction.pdf which seems to incorrectly label the terms

Comment: @hft Yes, I have edited this now, although my initial link seems to be in error

Comment: Your differentiation step isn’t correct. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/386789/146039) for the general treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimization of the free energy determines the equilibrium state of a system at fixed $(T,V,N)$. This minimization is done with respect to the partitioning of $V$ and $N$ under *fixed* temperature. We divide the system into two parts and seek the conditions that minimize the total free energy,
$$
   d(A_1+A_2) = 0
$$
under the constraints
$$
   T_1 = T_2 = T,\quad
   V_1+V_2 = V,\quad
   N_1+N_2= N.
$$
The minimizatio yields:
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial A_1}{\partial V_1}\right)_{T,N_1}
   =
   \left(\frac{\partial A_2}{\partial V_2}\right)_{T,N_1}
   \Rightarrow \boxed{P_1 = P_2}
$$
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial A_1}{\partial N_1}\right)_{T,V_1}
   =
   \left(\frac{\partial A_2}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,V_2}
   \Rightarrow \boxed{\mu_1 = \mu_2}
$$
These express the standard conditions of mechanical and chemical equilibrium (thermal equilibrium is maintained by the condition $T_1=T_2$).

Your mistake is to minimize $A$ with respect to $T$. In general, we minimize potentials with respect to their *extensive* variables while keeping their intensive variables fixed.